# Show results of employees whose age is equal to 65

Tags: mysql

Show results of employees whose age is equal to 65.
I want to get results whose age is 65 , i.e if any employee age comes to 65 years on 24-02-2022 his results I want to show, after 25-02-2022 his results should not display for the total 12 months, want to show for only one day.
Any help

```
SELECT id,
      first_name,
      last_name,
      floor(datediff(CURDATE(),date_of_birth)/365) as age,
      date_of_birth 
from employee 
where floor(datediff(CURDATE(),date_of_birth)/365)=65;
```

Sample data

```
employee name - James
 
date of birth - 1957-02-24

age - 65
```

At this date he is 65 years and should not display after this date, i.e from `25-02-2022` to `24-02-2023`

Comment: Please add sample data and the expected result

Comment: Sample data

employee name - James,

date of birth - 1957-02-24,

age - 65,
At this date he is 65 years and should not display after this date, i.e from 25-02-2022 to 24-02-2023

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT id, 
       first_name, 
       last_name,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURRENT_DATE) AS age, 
       date_of_birth 
FROM employee 
HAVING age = 65;
```

[TIMESTAMPDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) returns the amount of complete (not rounded) *units* between two dates.

---

> I want only exactly at the starting date when he is 65 years and 0 days.

```sql
SELECT id, 
       first_name, 
       last_name,
    -- TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURRENT_DATE) AS age, 
       65 AS age, 
       date_of_birth 
FROM employee 
WHERE date_of_birth = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 65 YEAR;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1a63622ffffef8167bc1be074a3a119b

Comment: Its showing employees age who are 65 years, All results whose age is 65 years 1 months, 65 years 2 months..so on all re showing.
But I want only exactly at the starting date when he is 65 years and o days.
I want to show only those results. 
As shown above in sample date only james data should display in results.

Comment: @Sonu Do you mean that you need only those employees who have the birthday today? Such variant added.

Comment: Yes @Akina, I want today results, those who have 65 years
Above query exact results are not displaying, please check once

Comment: @Sonu Provide in your question text: sample data (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts, 3-5 rows), desired output for this data. PS. Fiddle added. PPS. Check the datatype of the column - maybe it is not DATE but DATETIME/TIMESTAMP, and it contains non-zero time part?

Comment: thanks, got my result. The last sql query is my required condition

Comment: Following the above query, Please help me adding one more and final condition.
I want to get employees list who are 65 years. But I should get the results from  one month before, 
Suppose, an employee is turning 65 years old on 24-03-2022 then his results should display from today onwards, i.e upto 30 days it should display.(24-02-2022 to 24-03-2022)
I have written a query which is showing data after 65 years also, Please look into this

Comment: SELECT e.emp_id,e.first_name, e.date_of_birth,e.last_name from employee as e JOIN employee_job_info as eji on e.id=eji.employee_id where  (timestampdiff(year, e.date_of_birth,DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL '1' MONTH))>=65 or (e.date_of_birth = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 65 YEAR))

Comment: @Sonu Replace `WHERE date_of_birth = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 65 YEAR;` with according BETWEEN expression. For example, `WHERE date_of_birth BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 65 YEAR AND CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 65 YEAR + INTERVAL 1 MONTH;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242359/discussion-between-sonu-and-akina).